# Javascript cannot read value of an existing object?

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
if (rightArmy.pikeman.length > 0) {
        x = rightArmy.pikeman.length;
        console.log(x + "     X");
        console.log(rightArmy.pikeman[0].hp);
   /*291*/  while (rightArmy.pikeman[x-1].hp < 1 && x>0) {
            rightArmy.pikeman.pop();
            x--;
        }
    }
```

rightArmy.pikeman is an array, and last console.log shows that the value "hp" of rightArmy.pikeman[0] is "-80". This means that rightArmy.pikeman[0] MUST EXIST. Immidiately before that I check the value of X with console.log and it turns out to be "1". And then I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hp' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.fight (java.js:291)

Why wouldn't it be able to read it, how is this even possible? I labeled line 291 in my code for you.

Console is showing:

```
java.js:289 1     X
```

13:53:54.830 java.js:290 -80

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting this error because, when `x` reaches `0`, first your while loop checks for `rightArmy.pikeman[x-1].hp`, which is the same as `rightArmy.pikeman[-1].hp` when `x == 0`.
arrays are, usually, undefined at the index of `-1`.

an easy fix is to change the order of the conditions in the while loop -
`while (rightArmy.pikeman[x-1].hp < 1 && x>0)`
will become
`while (x>0 && rightArmy.pikeman[x-1].hp < 1)`,

or initialize x to be `rightArmy.pikeman.length - 1`.

Comment: But I do want x to have a new value after each iteration, this is why I am resizing the array.

Comment: then you could instead do this:

`while (rightArmy.pikeman.length > 0 &&  rightArmy.pikeman.hp > 1) ...`

and discard the x variable; it is redundant.

Comment: Both solutions that you have offered do not change anything, program is still throwing the same error.

Comment: No? You cannot just do .hp of rightArmy.pikeman, you need to provide an index number (it is an array), this is why I am using the x variable, to help me loop through the array. I just want it to stop when it reaches the end.

Comment: Since you're always looking at the last element of the array, it is not required. 

By the way, my suggestion with using `x>0` before the other condition is working for me, while your code throws the same error. maybe you forgot to save the file?

Comment: by not required, I mean you can always use `rightArmy.pikeman[rightArmy.pikeman.length - 1].hp` instead of the `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is, as @nadavvadan pointed out, the script executes x-1 before it checks if x > 0, so I solved the problem like this (because changing orders did not work):

```
if (rightArmy.pikeman.length > 0) {
    x = rightArmy.pikeman.length;
    while (x>0) {
        if (rightArmy.pikeman[x-1].hp < 1) {
            rightArmy.pikeman.pop();
        }
        x--;
    }
}
```

This way, the "x-1" condition is inside of the loop and will not be tested if X=0.

Comment: Notice that this code will potentially be different than the code that you have posted -
your old code breaks from the loop when it encounters a `pikeman` with `hp < 1`. this one doesn't. this one also always removes the last `pikeman` even if he is not the one with the low hp. I feel like this might not be the expected behaviour?

if all you're trying to do is filter out pikemen with `hp < 1`, and keep ones with `hp >= 1`, an easy solution is this:

`var pikemenWithLotsOfHP = rightArmy.pikeman.filter(function(pikeman) { return pikeman.hp >= 1})`